Sort and unzip a series of zip files by prefix
I moved to a new job where I'm sent a many zip files each day (about 50 every two days). They are formatted like this:

AAA - prefix, normally the time zone
YYYYMMDD - date like 20240126 for Jan, 26 2024
BBB - Initials of the author
alphanumeric up to ten characters

so I get something like this:
EST-20240128-AAA-Engineer.zip
EST-20240202-ZZZ-Receipts.zip
CDT-20240202-HHH-BluPrint.zip
EST-20231229-AAA-BluePrint.zip

What I want to do is to unzip each file into a folder structure by prefix and then by the zip file name so it would look like (I didn't sort these so ignore the order, I just want the layout):
\\
  EST\\
   EST-20240128-AAA-Engineer
   EST-20240202-ZZZ-Receipts
   EST-20231229-AAA-BluePrint
  CDT\\
   CDT-20240202-HHH-BluPrint

If at all possible, I'd like it to only unzip the archives one level deep as some of my teams will put their files directory into the zip file and others will place them into a subfolder, zip that subfolder and then send it to me.
I use a Windows 10 workstation so that would be best although I have access to redhat 7 server if that will be easier.
For the most part, I was doing this manually until two co-workers retired and instead of 20 in a week, I was getting over 200 in a week. I've looked at a few file management tools for windows but they seem to be limited in their options.
The second part about unzip only one level deep is optional. I can fix those manually instead of some more complicated script/program. If it is included, what I'm trying to avoid it this:
\EST\EST-20231229-AAA-BluePrint\EST-20231229-AAA-BluePrint\BluePrint-files
and instead have it look like:
\EST\EST-20231229-AAA-BluePrint\BluePrint-files

If you have to perform the same or similar steps again and again it it worth writing a script in your favorite batch/scripting language. As we don't know what you prefer and if you have the ability and permission to install other run-time s it is difficult to recommend something. On Windows you have plenty of alternatives like Batch, PowerShell V script and of course installable languages like Python.

I'd prefer PowerShell or batch. Python might be allowed but it is company laptop that need more approvals to install than I'd like to jump through.
